# The speed of light is 3*10^8 m/s and data transmission rate of optical fiber is ~100 Tb/s, how do we calculate data transmission rate?

Tags: bandwidth, transmission, optical-fibre

How do we calculate data transmission rate? Is there some formulas that is involved?

> Fiber optic cables beat copper in this department, and it isn’t even close. Fiber optic cables are made of tiny strands of glass, each about the size of a human hair, and use light pulses. Thus, they can carry a lot of data—up to 60 terabits per second—at speeds just slightly slower than the speed of light. Copper cables, limited by the speed at which electrons travel, can only reach about 10 gigabits per second.

https://blog.tripplite.com/7-reasons-you-should-choose-fiber-optics-over-copper

> The standard way to measure data transmission rates is via bandwidth. These days, it is measured in gigabits of data per second (Gbps), or even terabits per second (Tbps).
> Copper-based transmissions currently max out at 40 Gbps, whereas fiber optics can carry data at close to the speed of light. In fact, the bandwidth limits imposed on fiber are primarily theoretical, but have been tested to be measurable in hundreds of terabits per second.

https://www.cablexpress.com/education/blog/5-reasons-why-it-professionals-choose-fiber-optic-cables-instead-of-copper/

> Fiber optic cables transmit data much faster than copper wires do because fiber optics use the speed of light rather than the speed of electrons. Fiber optic Internet connections can range from 5 Mbps to 100 Gbps. This ensures no wasted time or productivity due to a slow Internet connection. Fiber optic cables also enable “symmetric speed,” which means that uploading and downloading speeds are equal.

https://www.fiberplusinc.com/services-offered/benefits-fiber-optic-cables/

I am really intrigued by how did we calculate data transmission rate of optical fiber or any transmission medium. What is the math behind it?

Comment: Two of your references seem flawed. "*Copper cables, limited by the speed at which electrons travel ...*" The electrical signal doesn't depend on the speed of electron travel through a metal - the electron drift veloicity is in the order of a few mm/s. It depends on the speed of the *wave* through the medium.

Comment: so optical fiber speed is speed of light wave? right? what about copper cable speed tho?

Comment: It seems that all three of your quotes contain nonsense so, where does that leave your question?

Comment: almost every place on internet tells that optical fiber is faster than copper cable. why are they telling so then?

Comment: _”Copper cables, limited by the speed at which electrons travel, can only reach about 10 gigabits per second”_ This is not true. Did you get this from some textbook?

Comment: speed of light in optical fibre certainly isn't 3*10^8 m/s...

Comment: https://www.techniques-ingenieur.fr/actualite/articles/nouveau-record-de-transmission-de-donnees-83486/ ...  178 Tbits/s

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're arguing against completely flawed references that are plain wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller no worries. I didn't know these sources were wrong. they all are from optical fiber companies didn't expect them to be this wrong. Where should I learn from then if every sources is so wrong? IDK if there are books for this subject https://www.ioenotes.edu.np/ioe-syllabus/instrumentation-ii-second-393..

Answer (score 6):

> because fiber optics use the speed of light rather than the speed of electrons

A complete nonsense.

Both methods propagate the signal at the speed of light in the particular media used. This can be assumed roughly to be 2/3 of the speed of light in vacuum in either case.

Both methods involve moving the electrons in the media somewhat (way below the speed of light).

Both methods imply that the signal goes over copper media (traces on the PCB) at least from the CPU to the transmitter/receiver circuit, be it optical or electrical.

The reason why optical cables are better *in our current technological context* (not per se) is that it is easier to make an optical cable that has more or less constant (or at least acceptably variable) properties over the signal bandwidth.

Comment: so what is the speed of optical fiber and copper cable ? which one is faster? both are faster according to what I understand from your answer.

Comment: We have faster (in the sense of bits per second) optical cables because our optical cable technology is better than our copper cable technology and not because of some physical limitation of the copper cables. In the sense of the information propagation speed (meters per second) both technologies are equal-ish at about 2*10^8 m/s.

Comment: The light is electromagnetic wave too. Just higher frequency then radio. Optical cables have wider band. The signal is digital, so more bits per second. Nothing to do with speed of electromagnetic wave's propagation.

Comment: @Fraxinus unless you're somehow going to change the conductivity of copper using "new technology", copper will always suffer from skin effect and this will limit the useful bandwidth of copper cable to much less than the useful bandwidth of optical fiber.

Comment: @ThePhoton see the answer. The signal goes over the PCB (copper) traces before it drives the laser. On the other hand, the technology maximum we have now in regard to the light is some kind of primitive amplitude modulation. Yes, the light with its hundreds THz bandwidth can do much more, but we don't have the technology to use much of these possibilities right now. On the other hand, we are trivially quite near the Shannon-Hartley theorem limits over copper-friendly frequencies.

Comment: @ThePhoton Litz wire gets around the skin effect and proximity effect. It's far too expensive to actually use for data transmission, but if you want to really push the limits, you can circumvent that limitation.

Comment: @fraxinus, 1. Driving a signal 5 mm over copper is not as challenging as driving it 100 km. 2. Fiber optics isn't limited to amplitude modulation, coherent modulation was first explored in the 1980s and is now becoming common again. 3. Being near the Shannon limit for copper technology means it isn't going to get better without super-cooling the entire system, while being far away from the Shannon limit for optics means that optics still have room for dramatic improvements in bandwidth efficiency.

Comment: @Hearth, maybe monatomic stranded Litz wire is the answer? Or superconducting cable (but that won't be "copper"). Then you're still left with the limitation that radio bandwidth is "only" 300 GHz or so and optics is 100's of THz.

Comment: @ThePhoton Good luck using terahertz signalling, though. The carrier wavelength isn't the same as the bandwidth of the system!

Comment: @Hearth no, but we're talking about possible future technology here. And we do achieve terabit data rates in fiber using WDM. Good luck doing that over copper with any current (or future) tech,  Litz wire or solid.

Comment: Individual WDM channels are 25 or 50 GHz wide, so getting to THz signaling only requires multiplexing 20 channels. Lots of undersea cables operate at multiple terahertz, as you would expect given their digital bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

First, the speed at which a signal propagates is irrelevant to bandwidth. Fiber optics, which have the highest bandwidths propagate signals at 2/3 the speed of light, but a 100 year old AM radio, cable of sending only a few thousand bits per second sends those bits at the speed of light. If you send a signal over a radio, it will get there first, then after a delay, a signal will arrive by fiber. The fiber signal will take longer but can contain billions of times more information.

As for your core question, the advantage of fiber comes down to frequency and attenuation. Frequencies greater than about 100-1000 MHz are strongly absorbed in metal cabling. This is why each new generation of USB/HDMI/DP/etc has required more expensive cables while imposing decreasing limits on their length. The higher frequency signals are more attenuated. Glass fibers also have this property, but (depending on the material) they attenuation becomes low around 150 THz and stays low until about 550 THz (this is why glass is clear at all visible wavelengths as well as more in the infrared and UV). Compared to the 0-.001 THz range on a copper cable, the ~500 THz range on fiber gives you millions of times as much bandwidth (depending on the exact fiber type, etc). This if you have millions of times more bandwidth, you can send data millions of times faster (at least in theory).

Comment: The fiber signal can't inherently contain more information than a radio signal could; it's just that the fiber signal has the entire spectrum available to it, where radio signals are limited in bandwidth by legislation. You can't legally transmit a broadband signal over the air, but there's physically no reason you couldn't.

Comment: Not sure I understand that point. A signal with higher bandwidth has more degrees of freedom and thus intrinsically takes more information to describe. Compared to a radio signal, even narrow band optical channels can contain orders of magnitude more information than wide radio channels.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only about the fibre itself, but also about the light source used to transmit the data and the light detector used to receive data. Any part of the system can and will affect the data rate, so the fiber may not be the limitation. Like with any other data transfer system, as long as the transmission medium itself does not distort the sharp transmitted data pulses too much to be blurry at the receiving end, the data will pass. There is no single formula for that, unfortunately.